# Using queryPurchases in an AysncTask by passsing the billing client to that class - not returning expected result

Tags: android, android-asynctask, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am implementing in-app billing. I am able to do all I want so far until it comes to checking the users previous purchases. In my first activity in `onCreate` I create an instance of my `BillingManger` class which handles all of the in-app billing.

I then call a `getPurchases` to retrieve a `PurchaseResult` object in the after this in the `onCreate` (& `onResume`) methods:

```
    //Creating instance....
    billingManager = new BillingManager(this, this.snackCoordinatorLayout);

    //Checking purchases....
    billingManager.getPurchases(this);
```

The `getPurchases` method creates a instance of a class which extends AsyncTask to query the purchases asynchronously. It takes a listener for the call-back and a `BillingClient` member variable (this is where I think I may be going wrong - explained why at the end.):

```
 //Querying purchases with AsyncTask
void getPurchases(PurchaseAsyncResponse listener) {


    CheckPurchasesAsync check = new CheckPurchasesAsync(listener, this.mBillingClient);
    check.execute();

}
```

Here's the  AsyncTask class. This returns a PurchaseResult via an interface callback which it successfully does.

```
public class CheckPurchasesAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Purchase.PurchasesResult> {

private PurchaseAsyncResponse listener;
private BillingClient mBillingClient;

CheckPurchasesAsync(PurchaseAsyncResponse listener, BillingClient billingClient) {
    this.listener = listener;
    this.mBillingClient = billingClient;
}

@Override
protected Purchase.PurchasesResult doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    return mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult) {
    listener.purchaseAsyncResponse(purchasesResult);

}
```

Now in the call-back is where I release something isn't working as I wanted.

```
@Override
public void purchaseAsyncResponse(Purchase.PurchasesResult purchase) {

    if (purchase.getPurchasesList() != null) {
        getMessage("mPurchaes NotNull");
        //Only need to get the first element - element 0 because their is only one product for now.
        if (purchase.getPurchasesList().get(0).getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            getMessage("Unlocking everything");
            unlockEveryThing();

        }
    } else {
        getMessage("mPurchases Null ASYNC");
    }

}
```

`purchase.getPurchasesList()` is null when it shouldn't be so I get a snackbar message called in the resulting else statement.

As part of debugging I called `queryPurchase` in another method. I have a button that allows the user to purchase premium features for the first time (that is suppose to disappear if I didn't have the problem I am asking about.) I have conditions set-up that show a message for different billing response codes. So as it stands now after buying for the first time, any time there after I display a message saying item already owned.

However, I quired the purchases in this block and was able to get back a successful `PurchaseResult` object and I was then able to use the `getPurchaseList` method to find out details about the purchase and it wasn't null like it is in the instance I explained about above. Here is that code snippet:

```
else if (responseCode.getResponseCode() == BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
     getMessage("Item already owned");
     Purchase.PurchasesResult PR = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);    


getMessage(String.valueOf(PR.getPurchasesList().get(0).getSku())); 
}
```

Is the problem that I am sending the mBillingClient to the AysncTask class and it loses its reference and all its meaning?

If so, how could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So in the end up I needed to use the `startConnection` method of the `BillingClient`. After this all worked as desired.